# Python shutil.move() inside a loop passes first instance but fails another

Tags: python, loops, security, conditional-statements

I am using shutil.move() to move files to another folder...potentially even reading in and making simple changes and then moving to another folder. The question is what safety logic can help omit errors...
EXAMPLE:

```
for file in file_list:
    if file == 'filename':
        shutil.move(source, destination)
    elif file = (something to make code fail):      #code errors out
        shutil.move()
```

This code will actually move the first file but then breaks and move nothing else. It is pertinent to keep files together as a batch...maybe a nested if? or just a general tip of security...and/or references you have found suitable to this type of question. thanks!  -newb circa forever

Comment: If you only want to remove specific files, then why have the loop at all?

Comment: Surely there can only be one file named 'filename' in your list. Is there an error or does the code just loop once and keep going?

Comment: @BenAlan ok maybe  ```if "file" in file:``` basically the question is if it passes in one loop it moves that file but say it fails in another, the original file that passed was moved, and now the batch is separated.

Comment: @DeepSpace because there is a an unknown number of files or any other reason you can think of

Comment: You can use path.exists('filename') on each file before trying to move them. If that fails, return an error instead of running the loop.